# Does Fineco Bank support trading on Tokyo Stock Exchange (TYO)?

Tags: stock-exchanges, online-banking

Does the Italian financial bank "[Fineco](https://fineco.it)" supports trading on the [Tokyo stock exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Stock_Exchange)? I can't manage to get this information anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Bonds**

Yes, but it depends on what specific type of bonds you want to buy.

> **Shares**

No it seems. Only UK, US, France, Germany, Dutch, Swiss, Italy, Canada and Spain.

I have a basic account, so not many options it seems. And I don't have a Yen balance so might be restricting, but I don't think that will be the reason.